# How can you generate a list of all possible significant interaction terms to be used in a GLM?

Tags: r, interaction

Is there a command that can return all significant interaction terms in R?

For example:

Input = c(age, gender,nationality)

output = list of significant interactions =
c(age * gender, gender * nationality, age * nationality * gender)

Comment: When you say "all possible significant", does this mean that you want to actually subset a model that you made to get significant interactions? Or do you just need a list of combinations of variables?

Comment: If you just want a list of all the possible combinations, you can also just write something yourself using `combn`, `paste`, and `apply`.

Comment: yeah, the words "possible" and "significant" put together is quite puzzling..

Comment: Sorry for the confusing terminology. I have removed "possible" from the sentence. I basically want R to test all possible interactions for significance and R to return a list of significant interactions.

Comment: Have you used stepwise regression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `broom` package:

```
library(broom)
m = lm(mpg ~ am * hp * disp, data = mtcars)
tidy.m = tidy(m)
tidy.m$term[tidy.m$p.value < 0.05]
```

Which gives you:

```
[1] "(Intercept)" "am"          "am:disp"     "am:hp:disp"
```

Is that what you want?

(This is assuming that the p value is the indicator of significance.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This does give me what I want so I have marked it such but I was hoping for something that does not involve fitting a model  prior to testing. Perhaps something based on values that interaction.plot derives and contains.

Comment: I'm not sure how can one know which interactions are significant without modeling. I haven't used `interaction.plot` before, but it too has to fit something to the data if it wants to tell you which interactions are significant, doesn't it? Also, you can always provide some code using `interaction.plot` and see if somebody can tweak it to do what you want.

Comment: Yes you are correct. interaction.plot uses the response variable and the terms you want to check for interaction.